# Are meta boosters physiologically addictive?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, black-lightning-2018

After Lynn creates the meta boosters in the third season, they are used as a metaphor for drug addiction. However, more than that, many characters treat them as an actual drug. Jefferson says that Lynn is addicted to the boosters, which she seems to concur with; Detective Shakur, who seems to be biased against metahumans but otherwise sympathetic, says that they will poison the minds of those who use them, which actually does occur when Chief Lopez injects herself with a meta booster. The boosters are compared with Green Light, which is definitely an actual drug.

On the other hand, when Tobias took the meta booster that made him invisible, he showed no signs of addiction or getting high, and nor did Gambi when he tested a booster made from Val's powers. Chief Lopez was already not in a good state. And of course, needless to say, the meta boosters are just limited versions of natural metahuman powers, which do not seem to be addictive, Lynn's accusation against Jefferson to the contrary.

So do the meta boosters actually cause physiological dependence or at least a high? Or are they just "addictive" in the same way that power itself is addictive?